# Show that $\dfrac{1}{|G|}{\sum\limits_{g \in G}} \phi_{g}v \in V^{G}, \ \forall v \in V$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

> Let $\phi : G \to GL(V)$ be a representation of a finite group G.
>
> Define $$V^{G} = \lbrace v \in V : \phi_{g}(v)=v, \ \forall g \in G \rbrace.$$ We know that $V^{G}$ is G-invariant.
>
> Show that $\dfrac{1}{|G|}{\sum\limits_{g \in G}} \phi_{g}v \in V^{G}$ for all $v \in V$.

If $v \in V^{G}$ then it is trivial that ${\sum\limits_{g \in G}} \phi_{g}v = v$.
The problem is that $v \in V$ and not specifically in $V^{G}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \phi(g)$. Then
$$\phi(a) p=
 \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \phi(a)\phi(g)= \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \phi(ag)=
\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in aG} \phi(g )=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} \phi(g )= p$$ Thus $\forall v \in V, \forall a \in G, \phi(a) p v = pv$ and hence $pv \in V^G$